# Why light Gallery is removing my original has from page url despite of setting hash:false

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightgallery

Why **lightGallery** is removing my **original** `hash` from page `url` despite i'm setting `hash:false`

**Question:** i don't want **lightGallery** to set any `hash` and remove any original `hash`

i'm using **lightGallery** setup like this:

```
 {
    src: imgUrl,
    thumb: imgUrl,
    hash:false
  }
```

here is my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REMLQr

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.hash = "my_original_hash";
    console.log('settt');
  },1200);
  $('#dynamic li').on('click', function(e) {
     var imgUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('data-src');
     $('.image-wrapper img').attr('src',imgUrl);
  });
  $('.image-wrapper').on('click',function(){
     var imgUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      $(this).lightGallery({
          dynamic: true,
          hash:false,
          dynamicEl: [{
              src: imgUrl,
              thumb: imgUrl,
          }]
      });
   });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #152836;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

.small {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -10px
}

.cont {
  text-align: center;
}

.page-head {
  padding: 60px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-head .lead {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.btn {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-lg {
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33333;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #152836;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #152836;
  border-color: #0e1a24;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-primary {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #eeeeee;
  transition: color 0.1s ease 0s, background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
}

.page-head h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.page-head h1 .version {
  bottom: 0;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
  position: absolute;
  width: 58px;
  right: -58px;
}

.demo-gallery >  ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.demo-gallery > ul > li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  list-style: outside none none;
}

.demo-gallery > ul > li a {
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.demo-gallery > ul > li a > img {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.demo-gallery > ul > li a:hover > img {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
}

.demo-gallery > ul > li a:hover .demo-gallery-poster > img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.demo-gallery > ul > li a .demo-gallery-poster {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
}

.demo-gallery > ul > li a .demo-gallery-poster > img {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.demo-gallery > ul > li a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a > img {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a:hover > img {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
}

.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a:hover .demo-gallery-poster > img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a .demo-gallery-poster {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
}

.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a .demo-gallery-poster > img {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.demo-gallery .video .demo-gallery-poster img {
  height: 48px;
  margin-left: -24px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 48px;
}

.demo-gallery.dark > ul > li a {
  border: 3px solid #04070a;
}

.image-wrapper{
   width:300px;
   height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.image-wrapper img{
      max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(1,67,163,.24), 0 0 8px rgba(1,67,163,.12), 0 6px 18px rgba(43,133,231,.12);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <span style="color:#fff;">click to preview image</span>
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080%20?Text=Digital.com%20C/O%20https://placeholder.com/">
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

That is because `hash` is not a valid option in `dynamicEl`: you should simply move it up one level and it should work. In other words, it should reside on the same level as the `dynamic` and `dynamicEl` keys:

```
$(this).lightGallery({
    dynamic: true,
    dynamicEl: [{
      src: imgUrl,
      thumb: imgUrl
    }],
    hash: false
});
```

Comment: Sorry Terry , i have misssed placed `hash: false` inside **dynamicEl**. now Edited my Question, Please see it.